# How to create a local ontology

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, iri

I want to create an ontology for my game application but it seems to me that I always have to choose an IRI for my ontology and then share the ontology online.

How can I create a local ontology with local subject IDs that have relations inside the application ?

Comment: you already tagged it with Protege, so why not using Protege as the ontology editor. And I don't understand why you thing the ontology has to be online. That's clearly not true. Just create the ontology and then use it - whatever this means in your use-case

Comment: What should I choose as an IRI then ? And how are the local IRIs defined ?

Comment: Well, because OWL is an ontology format for the Semantic **Web** and allows tries to follows the principles of **Linked Data**. If you don't care about resolution resp. access via HTTP, just use an arbitrary URI - who cares.It is still unclear how you use the ontology inside the application, but for many languages there are APIs to handle RDF/OWL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing an IRI for your ontology does not mean the IRI has to be a URL or that the URL needs to be resolvable and provide the ontology on retrieval. A URN will do - e.g., `urn:games:myGame` is  valid ontology IRI.

Once you save your ontology to a file, you can load it through the file name. This removes all needs for the ontology being shared online.